# Coffeescript source map doesn’t reference original files, but a new concated file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-contrib-coffee

I’m using [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) to compile the following:

- src

  - coffee

    - test1.coffee
    - test2.coffee
    - test3.coffee

into:

- dist

  - js

    - concated.js
    - concated.js.map

This works, but the problem is that a third file is generated in dist/js called “concated.src.coffee”, this is the file that concated.js.map references. This is of no use to me, when i debug in the browser i want the sourcemap to reference the original files, not a concated coffee file.

My grunt coffee config:

```
module.exports =

compileWithMaps:
  options:
     sourceMap: true
  files: 'dist/js/concated.js': 'src/coffee/*.coffee’
```

Any thoughts on how to make the sourcemap reference original files, not a generated concated coffee file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work!

Instead of letting [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) concat all .coffee files, I intstead changed the task configuration to compile all the files individually and place them all in a folder like so:

```
glob_to_multiple:
    options:
        sourceMap: true
    expand: true
    flatten: true
    cwd: 'src/'
    src: ['**/*.coffee']
    dest: 'dist/compile-coffee'
    ext: '.js’
```

To concat the files and the related sourcemaps, I used [grunt-concat-with-sourcemaps](https://github.com/wuifdesign/grunt-concat-with-sourcemaps) and configured the task like so:

```
your_target:
    options:
        sourceRoot: '../../'
    files: 'dist/concat-js/concat.js': [ 'dist/compile-coffee/*.js’ ]
```